# Zebra printing images without whitespaces

Tags: c#, printing, frameworks

I am using Zebra CPCL printer to print texts and images (.bmp). I am using Zebra SDK's method PrintImage for C# to print graphics, but the problem is that it keeps adding some white spaces before the image. I managed to eliminate whitespaces after a printed image by using SETFF, but is there any way to eliminate whitespaces before images?

```
        zebraTU.SendCommand("! U1 setvar \"device.languages\" \"line_print\"" + NL);
        zebraTU.SendCommand("! U1 setvar \"media.tof\" \"0\"");
        zebraTU.SendCommand("! U1 PAGE-WIDTH " + pagewidth + NL);
        ZebraPrintText(0, 2, 18, "After this line there is a white space");
        zebraTU.SendCommand("! UTILITIES" + NL + "IN-MILLIMETERS" + NL + "SETFF 0 0" + NL + "PRINT" + NL); 

        ZebraPrintImage("file.bmp", 0, 0, pagewidth, -1);
```